# Tkinter Python Execution Issue

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to execute code using tkinter GUI. I am not able to execute output. However, When I try only subprocess method it works fine. Can you please let me know what is wrong here.

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess

main_window = Tk()
Label(main_window, text="Name of Test").grid(row =0,column=0)
test = Entry(main_window, width=50, borderwidth=5).grid(row=0,column=1)
Def on_click():
    If test == "abc": subprocess.run(['python',r'C:\User\abc.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
Button(main_window, text='Run', command = on_click).grid(row=2, column=1)
main_window.mainloop()
```

Also, how to exit GUI window once process is complete?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guessing on what you were trying to achieve

```py
from tkinter import *
import subprocess

main_window = Tk()
Label(main_window, text="Name of Test").grid(row=0, column=0)
entry = Entry(main_window, width=50, borderwidth=5)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)


def on_click():
    entry_text_content = entry.get()

    if entry_text_content == "abc": 
        subprocess.run(
            ['python',r'C:\User\abc.py'], 
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        )

Button(main_window, text='Run', command = on_click).grid(row=2, column=1)

main_window.mainloop()
```

Please pay attention to the comparison of the input: I'm not comparing `entry` with `"abc"`, but I'm calling `entry.get()` at first to retrieve text from the entry, and then compare this text with `"abc"`.